# Modify only in specific files in Python

Tags: python, file

I have to add some lines in the beginning of the file to specific file in the directory like
(*.c or *.h).
I wrote the codes like below.

```
f = open('filename') 
text = f.read() 
f.close() 
f = open('filename~', 'w') 
f.write("This is the new first line\n") 
f.write(text) 
f.close() 
os.rename('filename~', 'filename')
```

It takes all the file in the directory and updates it.
But I need it should update some specific file.
How to do that

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to get all filenames that match a UNIX shell pattern (e.g. `*.c`). Also, you might be able to use the [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module to do inplace replacements to a file.

Comment: Thanks Man. I got the below link, which tells abt the glob module basically http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/glob/
http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/fnmatch/index.html#module-fnmatch